# Minimizing convex functions without compatible gradients

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I've been working on a minimization problem for a while, involving "simple" conditions, but haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried using Lagrange Multipliers and KKT, but the presence of $\frac{1}{\gamma^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in $\nabla f$ seems to make it impossible.

I need to minimize $f(n, \gamma) = \frac{3}{n} + \frac{2}{\gamma}$ with the primary constraint $g(n, \gamma) = \gamma \cdot(n^D + 3n^{D-1}) + 2n^D \le M$. Additionally, $\gamma, n > 0$.

Where $M, D$ are constants, and $\gamma, n$ are real variables to optimize over.

Should I be looking for a different optimization method?

---

So far, I have

$$\nabla f = \bigl< -\frac{3}{n^2}, -\frac{2}{\gamma^2} \bigr>$$

$$\nabla g(n, \gamma) = \bigl< \gamma\cdot(Dn^{D-1} + 3(D-1)n^{D-2}) + 2Dn^{D-1}, n^D + 3n^{D-1}  \bigr>$$.

Comment: So $n$ is not restricted to be an integer?  That's unusual notation, it might be more clear to call it $x$.

Comment: @littleO The problem itself is from a CS code optimization problem that reduces into a math problem. I could change the variables though.

Comment: Since the gradient is always nonzero we can safely that, if a minimum exists, it lies in the boundary of our domain, that is, when $g(n,\gamma) - M = 0$. In principle, Lagrange multipliers should be able to handle this. What sort of trouble have you found with it?

Comment: The $\frac{1}{\gamma^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ term in the gradient of F leaves me really confused on how to proceed.

Comment: You must try to solve the system of equations

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\nabla f(n,\gamma) = \lambda\cdot \nabla g(n,\gamma)\\
g(n,\gamma)=M\end{array}\right.$$

for $n, \gamma, \lambda$. Of course, you're only really interested in $n$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I believe that I explained in the post that I know how Lagrange works. The problem is actually solving that set of equations when some terms that show up in grad f do not show up in grad g

Comment: I am not sure I understand; do you want a closed formula, in terms of elementary functions? I don't think there's any particular reason to assume such a formula exists because $M$ and especially $D$ are not specified.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri it's not that I need a closed form with elementary functions, but rather that I need some kind of a strict bound on the minimization part.